# How to read a text value in from a label field in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have assigned the text in to a label control and i'm trying to read the text value of the control as below,

```
private DataTemplate GetDataTemplate()
    {
        var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            var rowGrid = new Grid
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                ColumnSpacing = 15,
                Margin = new Thickness(5),
                BackgroundColor = Constants.BackgroundColor
            };

    // Some code

            var isPaymentPlanEnding = new Label { };

            isPaymentPlanEnding.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "IsPaymentPlanEnding");


            if (isPaymentPlanEnding.Text.ToLower() == "true")
            {
                var highlightBoxView = new BoxView
                {
                    BackgroundColor = Constants.MMSGErrorRed
                };

                highlightGrid.Children.Add(highlightBoxView);
                highlightGrid.Children.Add(rowGrid);

                return new ViewCell { View = highlightGrid };
            }
            else
            {
                return new ViewCell { View = rowGrid };
            }
        });

        return dataTemplate;
    }
```

Could you please let me know, how do I read the value back from the label control.

Comment: Well, does your ViewModel implement INotify, and is the property correctly set?

Comment: if you are binding a Label to your model, why would you want to read the Label's value when you can just get the value from the model?

Comment: @Jason Is it possible to read the property value to a Boolean variable?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro Yes, it does

Comment: Basically, I want to read this property value to add some dynamic styles. I'm not able to read the value from IsPaymentPlanEnding property

Comment: "I'm not able to read the value from IsPaymentPlanEnding property".  Why not?

Comment: How do we read the property value in Xamarin? I need to edit the styles for one of the list item element when populating the listView. This code is in creating a template for the list view item source

Comment: A C# Property is just a C# Property.  Xamarin doesn't change anything about that.  "if (myModel.IsPaymentPlanEnding) ..."

Comment: @Jason Could you please tell me how will I be able to read through each instance of the list data with in the GetDataTemplate(). The GetDataTemplate() is the ItemTemplate value for a listview control.

Comment: @Jason I have updated the code in the question

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/customizing-list-view-cells-xamarin-forms-datatemplateselector/

Comment: @Jason Thank you for sharing the details